# Overlapping labels with the plot3D package in R

Tags: r, rgl, plot3d

I am currently creating a 3D scatterplot using the plot3D package in R, and I wanted to add data labels to my data points. However, some of my data points have the same values with each other, and I wanted to find a solution similar to `ggrepel` that would offset the data labels from the points so that the labels for those points would be legible. Sample code below:

```
library(plot3D)
names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
x <- c(1,1,2,3,4)
y <- c(1,1,3,4,5)
z <- c(1,1,4,5,6)

scatter3D(x, y, z)
text3D(x,y,z, names, add = TRUE, cex = 1)
```

The labels for A and B are currently superimposed on top of each other.

I tried to use the `directlabels` package as well, and it doesn't seem to recognize the text3D or the plot3D objects. Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plotrix::thigmophobe` function works out directions to try to stop labels from overlapping in 2D plots.  `rgl` doesn't have anything equivalent, and since you can rotate a plot, you'll always be able to rotate labels on top of each other.  However, the function below makes an attempt to place labels for one particular view so that they don't overlap.

```
thigmophobe.text3d <- function(x, y = NULL, z = NULL, texts, ...) {
  xyz <- xyz.coords(x, y, z)

  # Get the coordinates as columns in a matrix in
  # homogeneous coordinates
  pts3d <- rbind(xyz$x, xyz$y, xyz$z, 1)

  # Apply the viewing transformations and convert 
  # back to Euclidean
  pts2d <- asEuclidean(t(par3d("projMatrix") %*% 
                         par3d("modelMatrix") %*% 
                         pts3d))

  # Find directions so that the projections don't overlap
  pos <- plotrix::thigmophobe(pts2d)

  # Set adjustments for the 4 possible directions
  adjs <- matrix(c(0.5, 1.2,   
                   1.2, 0.5,  
                   0.5, -0.2,  
                  -0.2, 0.5), 
                 4, 2, byrow = TRUE)

  # Plot labels one at a time in appropriate directions.
  for (i in seq_along(xyz$x)) 
    text3d(pts3d[1:3, i], texts = texts[i], 
           adj = adjs[pos[i],], ...)
}
```

There are some problems with the function above:  it is based on `rgl::text3d` rather than `plot3D::text3D`, so the optional arguments are different; it plots labels one at a time, which can be inefficient if you have a lot of labels, it doesn't do error checking, etc.

Edited to add:

The unreleased version 0.99.20 of `rgl` adds a `thigmophobe3d` function to do this.  You'll have to get it from https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=234 or the Github mirror https://github.com/rforge/rgl for now.